# Camera keep changing object

Tags: animation, camera

Something weird is happening and I don't know why.

I imported an animated .fbx character from Maximo. Everything seems fine but whenever I try to move the position of the camera the character seems so stretch as if it is attached to the camera.

I tried to delete the camera but I keeps happening. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Kind of Dali effect? Could you upload your file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: It's probably parented to the mesh, click on the camera and hold down Alt+P. And clear the parent.